# DirectX graphic tools download blocked

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, directx

I have to work with DirectX on visual studio but when I debug I get the error that it failed to start the direct3D. After some research, I realized I need to install the optional feature graphic tools but when I try to install it, it stays locked ( doesn't progress at all at like 5%), when I try to cancel it, it simply doesn't and when I try to close windows I get a waiting screen ( preparing shut down, do not close windows)
I also tried downloading it from the command line with the `dsim` command but also failed.

Is there any way I can fix this?

EDIT : [image of My visual studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM9GN.png)

Error :

> D3D11CreateDevice: Flags (0x2) were specified which require the D3D11
>   SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system.
>   These flags must be removed, or the Windows 10 SDK must be installed.
>   Flags include: D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG

Tried using visual studio 2017 and 2019 (community) and my problem really seems to be solved with graphic tools that refused to download for some reason

Comment: Hey! Is there any way you can post screenshots, detailed error messages, and version numbers of the software? How long did you wait to get past the 5% loading? Did you try restarting the device (simple step but I've seen it fix many many issues before).

Comment: Hi, thanks I edited my post with image of the error, this error happens to me with both on visual studio 2017 / 2019, In the debug console I get:    
D3D11CreateDevice: Flags (0x2) were specified which require the D3D11 SDK Layers for Windows 10, but they are not present on the system.
These flags must be removed, or the Windows 10 SDK must be installed.
Flags include: D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG

Restarting doesn't help in any way, i waited for 30 minutes for the 5% loading the bar to progress and It didn't.